# How do I keep the previous equations from being displayed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I have a project where the user can insert a math equation in a single line using the split command. In the first loop the equation get solved correctly and displays the equation with the answer. The problem is with the second loop. It solves the equation and displays the equation with the answer but it also displays the equation from before.

```
using System;

namespace Calculator1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            double answer;
            double answer1;
            bool Continue = true;

            Console.WriteLine("\tCalculator");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------\n");

            Console.WriteLine("   Math Operations: ");
            Console.WriteLine(" --------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("  Multiplication: *");
            Console.WriteLine("        Addition: +");
            Console.WriteLine("     Subtraction: -");
            Console.WriteLine("        Division: /");

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your equation below:");
            Console.WriteLine("For example: 5 + 5 ");

            string[] values = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            double firstNum = double.Parse(values[0]);
            string operation = (values[1]);
            double secondNum = double.Parse(values[2]);

            while (Continue)
            {
                if (operation == "*")
                {
                    answer = firstNum * secondNum;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + firstNum + " * " + secondNum + " = " + answer);
                }
                else if (operation == "/")
                {
                    answer = firstNum / secondNum;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + firstNum + " / " + secondNum + " = " + answer);
                }
                else if (operation == "+")
                {
                    answer = firstNum + secondNum;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + firstNum + " + " + secondNum + " = " + answer);
                }
                else if (operation == "-")
                {
                    answer = firstNum - secondNum;
                    Console.WriteLine("\n" + firstNum + " - " + secondNum + " = " + answer);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry that is not correct format! Please restart!");
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n\nDo you want to continue?");
                Console.WriteLine("Type in Yes or No:");
                string response = Console.ReadLine();
                if (response == "Yes")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your equation below:");
                    string[] values1 = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
                    double firstNum1 = double.Parse(values1[0]);
                    string operation1 = (values1[1]);
                    double secondNum1 = double.Parse(values1[2]);

                    if (operation1 == "*")
                    {
                        answer1 = firstNum1 * secondNum1;
                        Console.WriteLine("\n" + firstNum1 + " * " + secondNum1 + " = " + answer1);
                    }
                    else if (operation1 == "/")
                    {
                        answer1 = firstNum1 / secondNum1;
                        Console.WriteLine("\n" + firstNum1 + " / " + secondNum1 + " = " + answer1);
                    }
                    else if (operation1 == "+")
                    {
                        answer1 = firstNum1 + secondNum1;
                        Console.WriteLine("\n" + firstNum1 + " + " + secondNum1 + " = " + answer1);
                    }
                    else if (operation1 == "-")
                    {
                        answer1 = firstNum1 - secondNum1;
                        Console.WriteLine("\n" + firstNum1 + " - " + secondNum1 + " = " + answer1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Sorry that is not correct format! Please restart!");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Continue = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
 Math Operations:
 --------------------
  Multiplication: *
        Addition: +
     Subtraction: -
        Division: /

Enter your equation below:
For example: 5 + 5
5 + 5

5 + 5 = 10


Do you want to continue?
Type in Yes or No:
Yes

Enter your equation below:
10 + 10

10 + 10 = 20

5 + 5 = 10  \\ I don't want this to appear


Do you want to continue?
Type in Yes or No:
```

Comment: Where is the second loop? I only see one `while` statement

Comment: You have the code to display the results inside the while loop twice.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is put the code that gets the user input into the `while` loop, and then let the loop continue if the user answers `"Yes"` at the end of the loop:

```
private static void Main()
{
    double answer;
    double answer1;
    bool Continue = true;

    Console.WriteLine("\tCalculator");
    Console.WriteLine("--------------------------\n");

    Console.WriteLine("   Math Operations: ");
    Console.WriteLine(" --------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("  Multiplication: *");
    Console.WriteLine("        Addition: +");
    Console.WriteLine("     Subtraction: -");
    Console.WriteLine("        Division: /");

    while (Continue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your equation below:");
        Console.WriteLine("For example: 5 + 5 ");

        string[] values = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        double firstNum = double.Parse(values[0]);
        string operation = (values[1]);
        double secondNum = double.Parse(values[2]);

        if (operation == "*")
        {
            answer = firstNum * secondNum;
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + firstNum + " * " + secondNum + " = " + answer);
        }
        else if (operation == "/")
        {
            answer = firstNum / secondNum;
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + firstNum + " / " + secondNum + " = " + answer);
        }
        else if (operation == "+")
        {
            answer = firstNum + secondNum;
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + firstNum + " + " + secondNum + " = " + answer);
        }
        else if (operation == "-")
        {
            answer = firstNum - secondNum;
            Console.WriteLine("\n" + firstNum + " - " + secondNum + " = " + answer);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry that is not correct format! Please restart!");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nDo you want to continue?");
        Console.WriteLine("Type in Yes or No:");
        string response = Console.ReadLine();

        if (response != "Yes") Continue = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Your Issue:**
 Its because you have the output code twice in the loop and both of them are displaying different variables.

**Solution:**

```
namespace Calculator1
{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        double answer;
        double answer1;
        bool Continue = true;

        Console.WriteLine("\tCalculator");
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------\n");

        Console.WriteLine("   Math Operations: ");
        Console.WriteLine(" --------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("  Multiplication: *");
        Console.WriteLine("        Addition: +");
        Console.WriteLine("     Subtraction: -");
        Console.WriteLine("        Division: /");


        while (Continue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter your equation below:");
            Console.WriteLine("For example: 5 + 5 ");

            string[] values = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            double firstNum = double.Parse(values[0]);
            string operation = (values[1]);
            double secondNum = double.Parse(values[2]);

            if (operation == "*")
            {
                answer = firstNum * secondNum;
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + firstNum + " * " + secondNum + " = " + answer);
            } else if (operation == "/")
            {
                answer = firstNum / secondNum;
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + firstNum + " / " + secondNum + " = " + answer);
            } else if (operation == "+")
            {
                answer = firstNum + secondNum;
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + firstNum + " + " + secondNum + " = " + answer);
            } else if (operation == "-")
            {
                answer = firstNum - secondNum;
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + firstNum + " - " + secondNum + " = " + answer);
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry that is not correct format! Please restart!");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nDo you want to continue?");
            Console.WriteLine("Type in Yes or No:");
            string response = Console.ReadLine();

            Continue = (response == "Yes");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So if a user inputs something like "a * b", how can I send them an error for entering an invalid input.

Comment: You need to use the `Int32.TryParse()`. Below is helpful demo on how to use it. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/how-to-use-inttryparse1